# Identifier unique in Ontology

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, rdfs

I wanted to know how i can create a identifier unique in my ontology exactly like relational database. (i wanted to have a identifier unique for every user).
Tanks,

Comment: Create the identifier by what? It is totally unclear what you're using. A programming language like Java, Linux command line tools,

Answer (score 1):

A common method of generating unique identifiers is to use a UUID. They can be generated using the SPARQL function [UUID()](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#func-uuid)

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
Every time that i create a new user in my ontology i wanted to have something like this => :user + StrUUID() => :user8cb55ac6-6abc-46af-aea5-f6c7ddbca658 .
is it possible?